# Transform map to key=value pairs

Tags: scala, maps

I have a `map: Map[AnyRef, AnyRef]`. What is the best way to map it in the following string

```
"key1=value1 key2=value2 ..."
```

In Java that's easy. I would just use it

```
map.entrySet()
    .stream()
    .map(e -> e.getKey().toString() + "=" + e.getValue().toString())
    .collect(joining(" "))
```

But how to do that in Scala?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
map.map{ case (a, b) => a.toString + "=" + b.toString}.mkString(" ")
```

Comment: You need `{}` instead of `()` to use `case`, and `=>` instead of `->`.

Comment: Fixed. Have no compiler next to me to check.

Answer (score 2):

Using a for comprehension with string interpolation,

```
(for ((k,v) <- map) yield s"$k=$v").mkString(" ")
```

Answer (score 2):

```
map map { case (a, b) =>  s"$a=$b" } mkString " "
```

*`.` is optional and use string interpolation to make it look good.*